# Display COLUMN NAMES from database through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to pull all the column names from my database 'settings' and list them in PHP.

A bit of research has come up with the following:

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM settings
```

but I don't know how to go about listing these off through PHP.
it would be helpful if any code posted was a prepared statement format, but not required.

Here is my PHP, it's giving me this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: sThumbWidth in /home/demomycm/public_html/subdomains/mercury/eshop/library/classes/class.settings.php on line 204
```

for every field in my database.

```
$loadColumns = array();

    $query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM settings";
    $result = $this->glob->dbConn->query($query);
    if($this->glob->dbConn->errno) {
        trigger_error('An error occurred whilst loading counties from the database.' . PHP_EOL . 'Query: ' . $query . PHP_EOL . 'Error[' . $this->glob->dbConn->errno . ']: ' . $this->glob->dbConn->error, E_USER_WARNING);
    } elseif($result->num_rows) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $loadColumns[$row['Field']];
        }
        return $loadColumns;
    }

$loadColumnsHtml = '';
    $loadColumns = $this->Settings->LoadColumns();
    foreach($loadColumns as $i => $field) {
        $loadColumnsHtml .= '<div class="home-stat-small-link">' . ($i + 1) . '. <strong>' . $field['Field'] . '</strong>.</div>';
    }
```

Comment: you'd echo it out exactly as you would any db select statement the listing code is identical

Comment: You can execute and fetch rows from that query exactly as is from PHP, just as you would any other query. Look at the column names returned.  `Field` is what you need.

Comment: Make DB Connection and get show values using echo function in PHP

Comment: You didnt' assign anything here: `$loadColumns[$row['Field']];`. Do you mean to do `$loadColumns[$row['Field']] = $row['Field'];` or `$loadColumns[] = $row['Field'];` or similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have `$loadColumns` as an array.
This line does nothing: `$loadColumns[$row['Field']];`
Basically your getting the value in $loadColumns with the key associated with `$row['Field'`] and not assigning anything.

You want something like this perhaps for that line:

```
array_push($loadColumns,$row['Field']);
```

Full code below

```
$loadColumns = array();

    $query = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM settings";
    $result = $this->glob->dbConn->query($query);
    if($this->glob->dbConn->errno) {
        trigger_error('An error occurred whilst loading counties from the database.' . PHP_EOL . 'Query: ' . $query . PHP_EOL . 'Error[' . $this->glob->dbConn->errno . ']: ' . $this->glob->dbConn->error, E_USER_WARNING);
    } elseif($result->num_rows) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
           array_push($loadColumns,$row['Field']);  //<-- this line has been changed
        }
        return $loadColumns;
    }

$loadColumnsHtml = '';
    $loadColumns = $this->Settings->LoadColumns();
    foreach($loadColumns as $i => $field) {
        $loadColumnsHtml .= '<div class="home-stat-small-link">' . ($i + 1) . '. <strong>' . $field['Field'] . '</strong>.</div>';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

use [describe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/describe.html)

```
DESCRIBE my_table;
```

Or in newer versions you can use [INFORMATION_SCHEMA:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html)

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_database' AND TABLE_NAME = 'my_table';
```

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL connection (deprecated) you can use:

```
mysql_list_fields
```

On PDO (recommend) use:

```
$query = $dbh->prepare("DESCRIBE tablename");
$query->execute();
$tableFields = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

On PDO you can also use `PDOStatement::getColumnMeta()`. But it has the status: EXPERIMENTAL